# How to broadcast a message to all clients connected to Socket server

Tags: c#, sockets

I am trying to make a program which can send commands to all clients from 1 server. I am stuck on sending commands to all clients. I currently do have this code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

namespace Server
{
    class Program
    {
        private static byte[] _buffer = new byte[1024];
        private static List<Socket> _clientSockets = new List<Socket>();
        private static int SERVERPORT = 5555;
        private static Socket _serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
                SetupServer();
            while (!Console.ReadKey().Equals("]")) //Stops the Console for closing after I type something in the console
            {

            }
        }

        private static void SetupServer()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Setting up server...");
            _serverSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, SERVERPORT));
            _serverSocket.Listen(100);
            _serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), null);
        }

        private static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
        {
                Socket socket = _serverSocket.EndAccept(AR);
                _clientSockets.Add(socket);
                Console.WriteLine("Client conntected");
                string response = string.Empty;
                response = Console.ReadLine();
                byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(response);
                socket.BeginSend(data, 0, data.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), null);
                _serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), null);
        }

        private static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
        {
            Socket socket = (Socket)AR.AsyncState;
            //int received = socket.EndReceive(AR);
            //byte[] dataBuf = new byte[received];
            //Array.Copy(_buffer, dataBuf, received);
            //string text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(dataBuf);
            string response = string.Empty;
            response = Console.ReadLine();

            byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(response);
            socket.BeginSend(data, 0, data.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), null);
            socket.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), socket);
        }

        private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult AR) 
        {
            try {
                Socket socket = (Socket)AR.AsyncState;
                socket.EndSend(AR);
            }
            catch {

            }
            //It gets alot of NullReferenceExceptions. It does work this way but I dont trust it.
        }

        public static void sendMessage(IAsyncResult AR)
        {
            Socket socket = (Socket)AR.AsyncState;
            string response = string.Empty;
            response = Console.ReadLine();
            byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(response);
            socket.BeginSend(data, 0, data.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), null);
        }
    }
}
```

I am able to send commands to each client when its 'their turn'. E.g. I start the server. I start client1 first and client2 second. When I type something in the console its client1's turn first so he receives the command. When I type something again client2 receives the command and so over and over.

I was wondering if there is a way to send it to all clients at the same time. Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using the Begin/End methods instead of the asynchronous ones, ie AcceptAsync, SendAsync etc? The code would become a *lot* simpler

Comment: I am new to networking so I followed some guides who brought me to this. I do not fully understand everything.

Comment: You're getting NullReferenceExceptions in SendCallback because you're passing `null` as the AsyncState - change the last parameter of the BeginSend calls from `null` to `socket` to fix that.

Comment: *foreach(var socket in _clientSockets)socket.BeginSend...* but beware, you're on multithreading and you're not protecting the list, that will lead to an exception if some client connects/disconnects while you're using the list.

Comment: @Gusman I've tried that. With this method you can send commands to all clients but still you have to connect them all. Which means if you open 3 clients. You have to type something 3 times to connect all 3 clients. Because you have to enter a command to re-loop and accept another incomming connection. Because it gets stuck at response = Console.WriteLine() untill you write something.

Comment: Then all your logic is flawed. FIrst of all, immediately when you have accepted a socket start accepting another one. Second, don't block the receiver thread waiting for console input. Third, create a mechanism to identify each socket (a dicttionary with a guid as key and the socket as value per example) so when you want to send something to someone you retrieve the socket throug it's id from the dictionary. Hope this helps ;)

Comment: This helps alot @Gusman thanks I am going to try it.